# Qual a diferença entre os modos r+ e w+ em Python?

Tags: python

Preciso abrir um arquivo para ler e escrever ao mesmo tempo, fiquei na dúvida em escolher entre o modos de acesso.

Se eu abrir o arquivo assim:

```
open('output.txt', mode='r+')
```

Ou abrir assim:

```
open('output.txt', mode='w+')
```

Qual será a diferença?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Veja a tabela disposta na [documentação oficial da função `open`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que em resumo:

- `r` abre o arquivo para leitura (mantem o cursor no início do arquivo);
- `w` abre o arquivo para escrita, apaga o conteúdo atual (mantem o cursor no início do arquivo);
- `+` abre o arquivo para atualização;

Vale notar que como o modo `+` habilita a atualização do arquivo, quando aliado ao `r` também permite a escrita, enquanto quando aliado ao `w` também permitirá a leitura.

Ou seja, ambos os modos `r+` e `w+` você poderá ler e escrever no arquivo, a diferença é que no `r+` o cursor é movido para o início do arquivo sem truncar o conteúdo, enquanto em `w+` o conteúdo é truncado. Em outras palavras, escrever usando o modo `r+` irá sobrescrever possíveis conteúdos no arquivo, enquanto com `w+` será garantido que o arquivo estará em branco antes de escrever.

Por exemplo, consideremos um arquivo `data.txt` com o conteúdo inicial `Anderson`. Ao fazer a alteração com `r+`:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r+') as stream:
    stream.write('Woss')
```

O arquivo final será `Wossrson`, pois a palavra irá sobrepor o conteúdo atual. Já fazendo com `w+`:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w+') as stream:
    stream.write('Woss')
```

O arquivo final seria apenas `Woss`, dado que o conteúdo inicial seria excluído antes de escrever.

> Cuidado com o processo de ler e escrever sobre o mesmo arquivo. Fazer a leitura irá naturalmente mover o cursor no arquivo até o ponto lido e a escrita sempre toma como base a posição do cursor. Você pode fazer uso da função `seek` para gerenciar manualmente a posição do cursor sem alterar o conteúdo se necessário.

Aliado a isso, o modo `a` irá abrir o arquivo para escrita movendo o cursor para o final do arquivo:

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as stream:
    stream.write('Woss')
```

O que geraria o arquivo com `AndersonWoss`.

Você pode ver a diferença em ação em https://editando-arquivo.acwoss.repl.run, o arquivo inicia com `Conteúdo inicial`, é solicitado o modo que deseja abrir o arquivo e o que deseja escrever nele. Após informar o texto o processo recomeçará.

```
Conteúdo do arquivo: Conteúdo inicial

>>> Qual modo deseja abrir o arquivo? r+
>>> Arquivo aberto com r+, o que deseja escrever? Anderson
Conteúdo do arquivo: Andersono inicial

>>> Qual modo deseja abrir o arquivo? w+
>>> Arquivo aberto com w+, o que deseja escrever? Stack Overflow
Conteúdo do arquivo: Stack Overflow

>>> Qual modo deseja abrir o arquivo? a
>>> Arquivo aberto com a, o que deseja escrever?  em Português
Conteúdo do arquivo: Stack Overflow em Português

>>> Qual modo deseja abrir o arquivo?
```

> Perceba que mesmo que a palavra inicial `Conteúdo` possua 8 letras, ela não será completamente sobreposta ao digitar `Anderson`, que também possui 8 letras; isso acontece devido ao caractere acentuado `ú` que ocupa 2 bytes, deste modo a palavra `Conteúdo` ocupa 9 bytes enquanto a palavra `Anderson` ocupa apenas 8, o que explica a letra `o` permanecer, pois ela estará no 9º byte na memória e não será afetado. Resumindo, muito cuidado com codificações multi-bytes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566011/1452488</sup>

Que resumindo (e traduzindo) fica:

- Para ler a partir do início: `r`
- Para escrever truncando o conteúdo: `w`
- Para escrever a partir do final (sem truncar o conteúdo): `a`
- Para ler e escrever truncando o conteúdo: `w+`
- Para ler e escrever a partir do início (sem truncar o conteúdo): `r+`
- Para ler e escrever a partir do final (sem truncar o conteúdo): `a+`

Adicionar o modificador `b` se deseja trabalhar com arquivos binários.

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser Sim, ele será modo escrita, sem sobrescrever o conteúdo, que permite a leitura. Porém, como estará sempre adicionando ao final do arquivo, você precisará mover o cursor manualmente antes de efetuar a leitura (respondendo a pergunta abaixo - previ o futuro xD).

Comment: Existe o modo a+?

Comment: Desculpe por ter apagado o comentário anterior, foi sem querer.

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser Sem problemas :D