# Substituindo as ocorrências de uma string em um arquivo texto. Diferenças apresentadas com diversos modos de abertura de arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

O objetivo é substituir cada ocorrência da palavra "secret" por "XXXX" no arquivo crypto.txt.

O meu código:

```
def crypto(arquivo):
    #palavras = []
    with open(arquivo,"r") as crypto:
        data = crypto.read()
        data =data.replace("secret","XXX")
    with open(arquivo,"w") as crypto:
        crypto.write(data)


crypto("crypto.txt")
```

O código acima funciona perfeitamente, mas eu fiquei pensando:
Eu abri o arquivo em modo de apenas leitura "r", depois gravei em "data" o texto do arquivo com a substituição, mas precisei novamente abrir o arquivo, só que em modo "w". Por que não já abrir o arquivo em modo de gravação ("r+"ou "w+") e, assim, não precisar abrir o arquivo duas vezes?
Fiz assim:

```
def crypto(arquivo):
    #palavras = []
    with open(arquivo,"w+") as crypto:
        data = crypto.read()
        data =data.replace("secret","XXX")
        #print(data)
        crypto.write(data)



crypto("crypto.txt")
```

Infelizmente, nem usando o modo "r+" nem "w+" o código funciona da mesma forma que o primeiro. O que está acontecendo?

Com "r+", ele cria uma copia do texto dentro do arquivo substituindo "secret" por "XXX" mas eu fico com o texto duplicado...
Com "w+" termino com um arquivo vazio...

Answer (score 1):

O problema da sua solução é que você não tratou devidamente o ponteiro do arquivo. Os processos de escrita e leitura de um arquivo utilizam o mesmo ponteiro e se a ideia é sobrescrever o conteúdo você terá que gerenciá-lo manualmente.

Quando você fez `open(arquivo, "r+")` você abriu o arquivo em modo de leitura e escrita com o ponteiro no início do arquivo.

[Qual a diferença entre os modos r+ e w+ em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372717/5878)

Assim, quando fez `crypto.read()` você armazenou em memória todo o conteúdo do arquivo, fazendo com que o ponteiro do seu arquivo fosse movido do início, onde estava, para o final do mesmo. Toda e qualquer operação sobre o arquivo a partir desse momento será feito com o ponteiro no final, por isso que a escrita em `crypto.write(data)` duplica o conteúdo no final do mesmo, pois você está literalmente falando para o Python fazer isso.

Para **sobrescrever** o conteúdo do arquivo, bastaria você mover o ponteiro novamente para o início após a leitura:

```py
def crypto(arquivo):
    with open(arquivo,"w+") as crypto:
        data = crypto.read()
        data =data.replace("secret","XXX")
        crypto.seek(0)  # Move o ponteiro para o início
        crypto.write(data)
```

> **Nota:** evite nomear uma variável local com o mesmo nome da função; não existe necessidade para isso e só causa confusão ao leitor do seu código, fora o fato de você estar perdendo momentaneamente a referência à própria função.

Mas é **muito importante** salientar que os dados que serão escritos deverão possuir o mesmo tamanho ou ser maior que o conteúdo atual do arquivo, caso contrário permanecerá lixo do conteúdo anterior. Por exemplo, se seu arquivo possuir o texto "pizza" e escrever "foo" a partir do início o resultado será "fooza" e não apenas "foo" como seria o esperado. Sendo assim, cuide para substituir seu "secret", com 6 letras, por "XXXXXX", também com 6 letras.

O modo `w+` sempre trucará o conteúdo do arquivo no momento da abertura e não faz sentido utilizá-lo aqui.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe `with` cria um escopo isolado. No seu primeiro trecho de código, o `crypto` do primeiro with se refere a uma variável X, o `crypto` do segundo with se refere a outra instância, uma variável Y.

**O que é um escopo?**

O escopo se refere a uma "caixa fechada" onde moram variáveis. Preste atenção no exemplo abaixo:

```
a = 2
def funcao():
  a = 3
  b = 4
  print(a) # -> 3
print(a) # -> 2
print(b) # -> erro
```

- `b` não existe fora da função. Pois o escopo dele é dentro da função. Quando a função terminar de executar, b será desalocado da memória.
- Chamar `a` dentro da função vai referenciar o "a de dentro do escopo". Chamar `a` fora da função vai referenciar o "a de fora".

Tem um motivo porque a maioria dos códigos que usam leitura de arquivos sugere o uso do `with` - arquivos podem ocupar muitos recursos. Você não precisa do `with`, mas o uso dessa sintaxe dá uma indicação de quando ele pode destruir o "leitor de arquivo" e efetuar operações como limpar a memória e fazer outras operações necessárias.

Comment: :Não entendi, pois  crypto.write(data) está dentro do with...

Comment: Com "r+", ele cria uma copia do texto dentro do arquivo substituindo "secret" por "XXX" mas eu fico com o texto duplicado...
Com "w+" termino com um arquivo vazio...

Comment: nao tenho certeza, mas acho que data ali naquele segundo with vai ser `None`. Pois `data` só existe no escopo do primeiro with.
Eu geralmente nunca especifico essas letras... É dificil precisar disso. Não precisa dividir em 2 withs  Por padrão ele abre "rw", acho (se nao especificar). https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Comment: Essa resposta está praticamente toda errada. O `with` não gera um contexto isolado, ele instancia um gerenciador de contexto, que transfere a responsabilidade  de controle do **contexto atual** a um objeto. Quando esse objeto é fruto da função `open`, o arquivo será aberto ao entrar no `with` e fechado ao sair; todas as variáveis criadas dentro do `with` pertencem ao escopo dele próprio, não é isolado.

Comment: E é quase sempre necessário especificar o modo de abertura de um arquivo, a menos que você utilize sempre apenas leitura, `'r'`, que é o modo padrão. Eu falei sobre esses modos em [Qual a diferença entre os modos r+ e w+ em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372724/5878)

Comment: Isolado em que as variáveis de fora não podem acessar as variáveis de dentro do contexto, e as de dentro podem acessar as de fora. Como em todos os contextos...

Comment: e ali era só ele abrir como rw e deletar aquela segunda linha de with. Não precisa abrir o arquivo duas vezes...