# Como salvar números inteiros em um arquivo txt no Python

Tags: python, array, lógica

Preciso salvar os números de 1 a 10000 em um arquivo .txt utilizando o Python. Pesquisei diversas maneiras de fazer isso, mas todas deram erro. A minha ideia era usar um contador em um laço de repetição, para salvar todos os números. Até o momento, o código está assim:

**arquivo= open("numeros.txt", "r")***

**ct= 0**

**while ct<=10000:**

Comment: A lógica básica está certa, então pode seguir com esse raciocínio. Só tome cuidado com a forma que abre o arquivo, pois ali indicou o segundo parâmetro como `'r'`, que será modo de leitura e não conseguirá escrever no arquivo como pretende. Para entender melhor todas as opções que tem, veja essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372724/5878

Answer (score 2):

```py
with open('numeros.txt', 'w') as stream:
  lines = (f'{number}\n' for number in range(1, 1001))
  stream.writelines(lines)
```

- Com `open('numeros.txt', 'w')` abre-se o arquivo para escrita
- Define-se um gerador `lines` que gerará cada linha que será escrita no arquivo
- Com `stream.writelines(lines)` escreve-se cada linha no arquivo

Answer (score -1):

Dentro do `while` será necessário a função `with` com dois parâmetros.
O primeiro com o nome do arquivo e a extensão, no caso nomeie de "contagem.txt"
a segunda com o tipo de manipulação que deseja realizar.

- `r` para leitura do arquivo.
- `w` para escrita. Caso usado sobrescreve o arquivo apagando o conteúdo ja existente.
- `a` para escrita. Diferente do `w`, cada vez que executado, escreve em uma nova linha, atendendo o problema proposto, já que, a cada interação um novo número será implementado.

`with open('contagem.txt', 'a') as salvar`: -->  Abrindo um arquivo em modo escrita

`salvar.write(f'{str(ct)}\n')` --> salvando os dados

`ct += 1` --> Atualizando o ct + 1.

```
ct = 0

while ct < 1001:
    with open('contagem.txt', 'a') as salvar:
        # OBS: str(ct) --> necessario o casting de int para str
        # a extenção .txt permite somente dados em strings.
        salvar.write(f'{str(ct)}\n')
        ct += 1
```

Comment: Detalhe: `f'{str(ct)}\n'`, ao usar as *f-strings* você não precisa converter o número em string, pois a própria interpolação na string resolverá isso para você: `f'{ct}\n'`. A conversão só seria necessária em caso de concatenação: `str(ct) + '\n'`

Comment: Não seria melhor abrir o arquivo apenas uma vez fora do `while`, em vez de abri-lo e fechá-lo 1000 vezes? Vale lembrar também que `with` não é uma função, e sim [um *statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). A função que recebe 2 parâmetros, no caso, é `open`