# Como transformar um texto que peguei de um site com web scraping em um arquivo txt?

Tags: python

```
htmlPagina10 = pagina.locator('xpath=exemplo')
print(htmlPagina10.text_content())
```

estou usando python

eu usei essa primeira linha do código para localizar uma parte especifica de um texto da internet.

e a segunda linha para printar a parte especifica no terminal

e esta funcionando tudo certo, esta encontrando e printando no terminal

porem eu quero copiar o texto e colocar ele em um arquivo txt, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar a função `open` para abrir um arquivo no [modo escrita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372717/5878) e escrever o texto nele:

```py
htmlPagina10 = pagina.locator('xpath=exemplo')

with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as stream:
  stream.write(htmlPagina10.text_content())
```

Isso irá gerar o arquivo `resultado.txt` com o conteúdo que deseja.